# Django FormView - Input Field not saving into DB

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

So, I am trying to use the input fields to add info into them and then save it. As of right now, I am not receiving any errors when I try and submit the form, but its also not creating objects either. Can anyone see the error? Would appreciate some help.

Here is my `client_setup.py` form:

```
from django import forms

from producer.models import Client

class ClientSetupForm(forms.Form):

    company_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()

    def clean_company_name(self):
        company_name = self.cleaned_data.get('company_name')

        pass

    def clean_first_name(self):
        first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')

        pass

    def clean_last_name(self):
        last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')

        pass
```

`pod_funnel.py` views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms.client_setup import ClientSetupForm
from .forms.podcast_setup import PodcastSetupForm
from .forms.episode_info import EpisodeInfoForm
from .forms.image_files import EpisodeImageFilesForm
from .forms.wordpress_info import WordpressInfoForm
from .forms.chapter_marks import ChapterMarksForm
from .forms.show_links import ShowLinksForm
from .forms.tweetables import TweetablesForm
from .forms.clicktotweet import ClickToTweetForm
from .forms.schedule import ScheduleForm

from producer.models import Client, Production, ChapterMark, ProductionLink, ProductionTweet, Podcast

from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class ClientSetupView(FormView):
    template_name = 'pod_funnel/forms.html'
    form_class = ClientSetupForm
    success_url = '/podfunnel/ClientSetupView/'

    def form_valid(self, form):

        form.clean_first_name()
        form.clean_last_name()

        return super(ClientSetupView, self).form_valid(form)
```

And `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text
from producer import myFields
from randomslugfield import RandomSlugField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core import urlresolvers

class Client(TimeStampedModel):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def full_name(self):
        return smart_text('%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_text(self.company_name)

class Podcast(TimeStampedModel):
    PRODUCTION_NAMES_HELP = 'You can use the following placeholders in the name: EPISODE_GUEST_FULL_NAME, ' \
                            'EPISODE_NUMBER, EPISODE_TITLE'

    BASE_PROD_DEFAULT_TITLE_FORMAT = 'EPISODE_NUMBER EPISODE_GUEST_FULL_NAME - EPISODE_TITLE'
    SECONDARY_PROD_DEFAULT_TITLE_FORMAT = 'EPISODE_TITLE with EPISODE_GUEST_FULL_NAME'

    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name='Auphonic Preset UUID')

    dropbox_service = models.ForeignKey(Service, null=True, blank=True, related_name='dropbox_service_id',
                                        limit_choices_to={'provider': Service.DROPBOX}, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    soundcloud_service = models.ForeignKey(Service, null=True, blank=True, related_name='soundcloud_service_id',
                                           limit_choices_to={'provider': Service.SOUNDCLOUD}, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    libsyn_service = models.ForeignKey(Service, null=True, blank=True, related_name='libsyn_service_id',
                                       limit_choices_to={'provider': Service.LIBSYN}, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    archiveorg_service = models.ForeignKey(Service, null=True, blank=True, related_name='archiveorg_service_id',
                                           limit_choices_to={'provider': Service.ARCHIVEORG}, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    blubrry_service = models.ForeignKey(Service, null=True, blank=True, related_name='blubrry_service_id',
                                        limit_choices_to={'provider': Service.BLUBRRY}, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    youtube_service = models.ForeignKey(Service, null=True, blank=True, related_name='youtube_service_id',
                                        limit_choices_to={'provider': Service.YOUTUBE}, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    wordpress_config = models.ForeignKey(WordpressConfig, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    itunes_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)

    soundcloud_account = models.ForeignKey(SoundcloudConfig, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    twitter_account = models.ForeignKey(TwitterConfig, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    podcast_twitter_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)
    podcast_guest_twitter_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)
    schedule_tweets_on_publish = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Schedule 'First Week Tweets' when "
                                                                                "production is published")
    podcast_click_to_tweet_format = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,
                                                     help_text='You can use the following placeholders in the text: '
                                                               'PODCAST_TWITTER_NAME, PODCAST_GUEST_TWITTER_NAME, '
                                                               'WORDPRESS_URL')

    production_auto_email_test_mode = models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='While Test Mode is enabled, Auto'
                                                                                  'email is sent to FullCast admin team'
                                                                                  'only. If disabled it will also be'
                                                                                  'sent to client email.')
    production_auto_email_subject_format = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    production_auto_email_format = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,
                                                    help_text='You can use the following placeholders in the text: '
                                                              'CLIENT_FIRST_NAME, WORDPRESS_URL, TRANSCRIPTION_URL, '
                                                              'EPISODE_GUEST_FIRST_NAME, EPISODE_GUEST_LAST_NAME, '
                                                              'EPISODE_NUMBER, CLICK_TO_TWEET_LINK, ITUNES_URL')

    base_production_name_format = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,
                                                   default=BASE_PROD_DEFAULT_TITLE_FORMAT)
    secondary_production_name_format = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,
                                                        default=SECONDARY_PROD_DEFAULT_TITLE_FORMAT,
                                                        help_text=PRODUCTION_NAMES_HELP)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_text(self.name)
```

**----------------------------------------------------**

**UPDATE**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://192.168.33.10:8000/podfunnel/podcastsetup/

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('producer',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'registration',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_extensions',
 'randomslugfield',
 'adminsortable2',
 'crispy_forms')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/vagrant/fullcast_project/producer/views/pod_funnel.py" in podcastsetup
  132.      instance.save()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  700.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  728.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  812.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  851.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1039.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1064.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  95.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /podfunnel/podcastsetup/
Exception Value: null value in column "client_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (5, 2016-06-16 05:55:43.067263+00, 2016-06-16 05:55:43.06732+00, Awesome Show!, , null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, http://html-color-codes.info/, null, t, t, EPISODE_NUMBER EPISODE_GUEST_FULL_NAME - EPISODE_TITLE, EPISODE_TITLE with EPISODE_GUEST_FULL_NAME, null).
```

**----------------------------------------------------**

`client_setup.py` forms:

```
from django import forms

from producer.models import Client
# from producer.models import Podcast

class ClientSetupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = Client
        fields = ['company_name', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def clean_company_name(self):
        company_name = self.cleaned_data.get('company_name')

        return company_name

    def clean_first_name(self):
        first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')

        return first_name

    def clean_last_name(self):
        last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')

        return last_name
```

`podcast_setup.py` forms:

```
from django import forms

from producer.models import Podcast

class PodcastSetupForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:

    model = Podcast
    fields = ['name', 'itunes_url']

def clean_name(self):
    name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')

    return name

def clean_itunes_url(self):
    itunes_url = self.cleaned_data.get('itunes_url')

    return itunes_url
```

`pod_funnel.py` views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms.client_setup import ClientSetupForm
from .forms.podcast_setup import PodcastSetupForm
from .forms.episode_info import EpisodeInfoForm
from .forms.image_files import EpisodeImageFilesForm
from .forms.wordpress_info import WordpressInfoForm
from .forms.chapter_marks import ChapterMarksForm
from .forms.show_links import ShowLinksForm
from .forms.tweetables import TweetablesForm
from .forms.clicktotweet import ClickToTweetForm
from .forms.schedule import ScheduleForm

from producer.models import Client, Production, ChapterMark, ProductionLink, ProductionTweet, Podcast

from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def clientsetup(request):

title = 'Client Setup'
title_align_center = True
form = ClientSetupForm(request.POST or None)
context = {
    "title": title,
    "form": form
}

if form.is_valid():

    instance = form.save(commit=False)

    company_name = form.cleaned_data.get("company_name")
    first_name = form.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
    last_name = form.cleaned_data.get("last_name")

    instance.company_name = company_name
    instance.first_name = first_name
    instance.last_name = last_name

    instance.user = request.user

    instance.save()

    return render(request, "pod_funnel/forms.html", context)

else:

        return render(request, "pod_funnel/forms.html", context)

def podcastsetup(request):

title = 'Podcast Setup'
title_align_center = True
form = PodcastSetupForm(request.POST or None)
context = {
    "title": title,
    "form": form
}

if form.is_valid():

    instance = form.save(commit=False)

    name = form.cleaned_data.get("name")
    itunes_url = form.cleaned_data.get("itunes_url")

    instance.name = name
    instance.itunes_url = itunes_url

    instance.save()

    return render(request, "pod_funnel/forms_podcast_setup.html", context)

else:

        return render(request, "pod_funnel/forms_podcast_setup.html", context)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- The `clean_<fieldname>` methods must return a value - yours just `pass`.
- You should not be calling those methods manually in your view anyway. These are called [as part of the built-in form validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation). In your case you aren't actually performing any logic in those functions and can do away with them completely.
- You should never be modifying `form['cleaned_data']` directly.
- Your data isn't being saved anywhere because you aren't doing anything with it after validating the form. You probably want to use a [model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/) instead of a regular form, as this has built-in methods for saving the form data to a model after validation.

I'd suggest you spend some time studying the documentation on model forms (and forms in general) as your current implementation seems to suggest a number of misconceptions about how Django's Form API works.

**Edit** - comments on the updated code that uses a `ModelForm`:

- As above, your use of `clean_<fieldname>` methods is wrong and unnecessary. Remove these completely and don't edit `form['cleaned_data`]` directly.
- The error you are getting is because your `Podcast` model has a *required* foreign key to `Client`, but this value is never set. Your `ModelForm` only sets the `name` and `itunes_url`. You will need either to add this field to the form, or to set this value manually before saving the form instance.

Comment: Thanks for the input. New to django though, I was using this [documentation on handling class views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#basic-forms) to go through this path, but it has been a little bumpy. I actually have another copy of the project but with `ModelForms`. It works pretty well with the same inputs by keeping the data except for 1 issue. When I try to save one of the forms it gives me a `nullvalue` error on a `client_id` (Check update on question). If you have any suggestion on that error. Let me know.

Comment: Can't really comment without seeing the code that generates that error.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I added the code in the update section below the error log. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've edited the answer with comments on the new code.

Comment: Awesome! Decided to add it in the form. Thanks for the help.